# Calculo aritmético en el save() del model, no funciona en el UpdateView, solo en el CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-models

Tengo dos modelos Recepcion y RecepcionItem, utilizando formset. Estoy haciendo el siguiente calculo en el save() del model RecepcionItem:

```
self.valor_euro = self.recepcion.valor_euro # valor euro desde models Recepcion

self.precio_venta_cl = self.item.precio_venta * self.valor_euro
```

Al crear (CreateView) funciona perfecto, pero en el update modifico valor_euro en Recepcion y los items no se actualizan (o recalculan) en RecepcionItem.

Mi modelos:

```
class Recepcion(models.Model):
n_recep = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True, default=Codigo_completo)
nombre_empresa = models.ForeignKey('clientes.Clientes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
valor_euro = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.n_recep)



class RecepcionItem(models.Model):
recepcion = models.ForeignKey('recepcion.Recepcion', related_name='tablarecepcion',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
item = models.ForeignKey('equipos.Equipos', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
codigo = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='-', null=True, blank=True)
valor_euro = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=800, blank=True)
precio_venta_cl = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.item)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.codigo = self.item.codigo
    self.valor_euro = self.recepcion.valor_euro #valor euro desde models Recepcion

    # precio venta
    self.precio_venta_cl = self.item.precio_venta * self.valor_euro
    ...
    return super(RecepcionItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente agregué save() al modelo principal (Recepcion) y de esta forma ahora realiza las operaciones.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for item in RecepcionItem.objects.filter(recepcion=self.id):
        # peso total
        item.peso_total = item.reparable * item.peso
        item.save()
    return super(Recepcion, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```